# How to connect to Cassandra within a docker container in order to view on DBVisualize on host machine?

Tags: docker, cassandra, datastax, dbvisualizer

I currently have a Docker container with Cassandra running within. I am trying to get a visual view using DBVisualizer of said Cassandra. I am using DataStax's Cassandra JDBC driver.

I run my container like so:

```
docker run --rm -it --net=host -p 9042:9042 [docker image from repo]
```

The container has an ip of `10.0.72.3`

Outside of this container, I am trying to access this cassandra by connecting to:
`jdbc:cassandra:Database=Test Cluster;Port=9042;Server=10.0.72.3;`

However,  I keep getting:

```
The connection failed: No Cluster node is available..
```

I have attempted to change `cassandra.yaml` and change ports, but I am still stuck. Any assistance is appreciated. Thank you

Comment: That should work. I see that you're not running the container in background (you can do so with -d flag). Is it possible you stopped the container in the terminal it was running? Also, can you try without --net flag? I haven't used that option before and don't have it in my version of docker.

Comment: I've tried without the --net flag as well. It has not seemed to work. I've ended up abandoning DBVisualizer for now, using TablePlus instead.